# Highcharts / Highstock stepline with integer values drawing halfsteps?

Tags: highcharts

How can this be possible? All the values are integers and that vertical tick is set as increments of 1.

When I zoom into such halfstep period, the halfstep is not happening.

[image: stepline with halfsteps]

[image: zoomed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not supported, only what you can do is catch setExtrems() event (zoom) and load new data with new steps.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData